# upload audio file on PHP server from Android - uploaded file with size zero

Tags: php, android, file-upload

In my Android application I recorded audio and send it to PHP server. But in PHP server file is created with size ZERO. Here is my code,

**Android upload file**

```
public MultipartUtility(String requestURL)
        throws IOException {
    // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
    boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";
    URL url = new URL(requestURL);
    httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
    httpConn.setDoOutput(true);    // indicates POST method
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
}

public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
            throws IOException {
        String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            //file uploading done through chunk
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            Log.d("sending",buffer.toString());
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();

    }


public String finish() throws IOException {
        String response = new String();
        // checks server's status code first
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            response=reader.readLine();
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

**PHP Code**

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        //print_r($data);
        $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/feedbackmsg"; // Full Path
        $filename = $dir.'/testing.amr';
        $fp = fopen($filename, 'wb');
        fwrite($fp, $data);
        fclose($fp);

        $size = filesize($filename);
        $fp = fopen($filename, 'rb');
        $data = fread($fp, $size);
        fclose($fp);
        $n = strlen($data);
        for ($i=0; $i<$n; ++$i) {
            ord(substr($data, $i, 1)) . ' ';
        }
```

**File is uploaded having size ZERO.**

Comment: And how many bytes were sent? I see no code where in you use and log a totalBytesRead variable.

Comment: `Log.d("sending",buffer.toString())` For an audio file that makes not much sense. Better log bytesRead. But... What did you see of it?

Comment: No exceptions thrown?

Comment: What is the value of uploadFile.getAbsolutePath()?

Comment: `$n = strlen($data);` If you put that on the second line. Then what would be the value of $n? Print it. Echo it.

Comment: I put logs  Log.d("sending","bytesRead = "+bytesRead+" == "+buffer.toString()); it print  bytesRead = 4096 == [B@1e6c63
 bytesRead = 4096 == [B@1e6c63
bytesRead = 3334 == [B@1e6c63

Comment: uploadFile.getAbsolutePath() == /storage/emulated/0/recording.amr

Comment: $n = strlen($data); print response = 0

Comment: Missing an outputStream.close();

Comment: `httpConn.setDoInput(true);` you are not reading from the input stream.

Comment: httpConn.setDoInput(true); I am reading from input stream. Please check the updated question.

Comment: Yes I write this code BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream())); So what ?

Comment: Sorry, i dont know what is wrong and not have my code at hand at the moment.